# Thymeleaf and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I trying display `html` template with `thymeleaf` loop like:

```
<th:block th:each="ticket : ${tickets}">
    <div th:id="'ticket_' + ${ticket.ticketId}" th:include="${ticket.templateName}"></div>
    <div th:id="${ticket.ticketId}" th:if="${#strings.toString(ticket.ticketStatus)} == 'CANCELED'" th:include="'canceled'"></div>
</th:block>
```

`If ticketStatus == 'CANCELED'` I include html with js code which alert parent ID and its ID different for all elements. But JS alert same id (id of first element). Why so?
UPD: JavaScript part:

```
    <script class='idForScript' th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var id = $('.idForScript').parent().attr('id');
    alert(id);
    $('#ticket_'+id).find('.sortable').prepend('<div style="z-index: 232; background: grey; color:red; width:100%; height:100%; opacity:0.9; text-align:center; position: absolute;"><span style="position: absolute; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;left: 0; right: 0; top:35%;"><h1 style="font-weight:900;">YOUR TICKET WAS CANCELED</h1></span></div>');
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include your javascript part?

Comment: @Lukehey yes, updated

Comment: The jQuery selector `'.idForScript'` selects all elements with the `idForScript` class. Calling `parent` on the jQuery object which wraps this selection returns a jQuery object wrapping the parent of the first element of the wrapped collection - I'm not sure that jQuery guarantees which one this will be, but it would appear that you get the same one each time. Why not just conditionally include the html using Thymeleaf? This isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by skipping the include part quite easily. This is all in one file now.
Your script:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    function yourFunction(id){
        alert(id);
        // Rest of your code.
    }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Inside your iteration:

```
<div th:id="${ticket.ticketId}" th:if="${#strings.toString(ticket.ticketStatus)} == 'CANCELED'">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/ 
        $(function() {
            yourFunction([[${ticket.ticketId}]]);
         });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: But it's not the best approach. take a look [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/270723/why-is-it-a-good-practice-to-keep-javascript-code-in-separate-files) for example.

Comment: Well he can of course put that first fragment into a new js file. But having a new HTML file included each time the condition is fulfilled isn't that practical either. One of the answers in your source is don't repeat yourself, which is exactly what OP's code is doing.